# I need to make a button using HTML, CSS, and Javascript to change font color from to red when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using CodePen for an assessment in the basics of creating a website. I am using the HTML column. I am trying to make the font color blue for the following sentence "Today is a beautiful sunny day!"

Here is what I have written so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      h1  {color: red; } 
      #redText {color: red } 
         </style>
     <title>your site</title> 
  </head>
   <title>My Name Here</title> 
   </head> 
    
  <body>
    <h1> Today's Weather Report</h1>
    <div class="redText">
    <p id="blueText"> Today is a beautiful sunny day!</p>
      
     <button type="button">Push</button> 
   
    <script>
     function changeColor(newColor){var elem = document.getElementById('blueText');
    elem.style.color = newColor;}
    <button onClick="changeColor(blue);">PUSH</button>
    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

This what the script I have written displays:

Today's Weather Report (The font color for this sentence is supposed to be red and it is.)

Today is a beautiful sunny day! (This sentence should be blue when the button labeled `PUSH` is clicked on, but it is still black.)

There is a button located here that says `PUSH`

Comment: You have two `title` tags and two closing `head` tags.

Comment: You should run your code through an HTML validator or at least use a good editor, which would flag some of your problems. At a bare minimum, properly indent your markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove this code from the script
`<button onClick="changeColor(blue);">PUSH</button>`

and place the function call above in html button tag.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      h1  {color: red; } 
      #redText {color: red } 
         </style>
     <title>your site</title> 
  </head>
   <title>My Name Here</title> 
   </head> 
    
  <body>
    <h1> Today's Weather Report</h1>
    <div class="redText">
    <p id="blueText"> Today is a beautiful sunny day!</p>
      
     <button type="button" onClick="changeColor('blue')">Push</button> 
   
    <script>
     function changeColor(newColor){
       var elem = document.getElementById('blueText');
       elem.style.color = newColor;
     }
    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

don't put button in script :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      h1  {color: red; } 
      #redText {color: red } 
         </style>
     <title>your site</title> 
  </head>
   <title>My Name Here</title> 
   </head> 
    
  <body>
    <h1> Today's Weather Report</h1>
    <div class="redText">
    <p id="blueText"> Today is a beautiful sunny day!</p>
    <button onClick="changeColor('blue');">PUSH</button>

   
    <script>
     function changeColor(newColor){
       var elem = document.getElementById('blueText');
       elem.style.color = newColor;
     }
    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

And don't forget to put color parameter inside **quotation marks** because it's string property!

Comment: When the code <button onClick="changeColor(blue);">PUSH</button> is deleted from script, the text color still does not change from black to blue.

Comment: @LenakelIsaka Don't forget to put color parameter inside quotation marks because it's string property!

Answer (score 0):

The title appears to suggest the text is to change from `blue` to `red` but is perhaps missing a word? Anyway - you could easily toggle the color of the text in a couple of ways - both shown below. Incidentally you have not closed the `DIV` tag ( `<div class='redText'>` ) so I removed it from the snippet.

```js
const clickhandler=function(e){
  let p=this.previousElementSibling;
  p.className=p.className=='blueText' ? 'redText' : 'blueText'
}
const togglehandler=function(e){
  this.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('redText');
}

document.querySelector('button[name="bttn-1"]').addEventListener('click',clickhandler);
document.querySelector('button[name="bttn-2"]').addEventListener('click',togglehandler);
```

```css
h1 { color:red } 
.redText { color:red!important; }
.blueText{ color:blue; }
```

```html
<h1> Today's Weather Report</h1>

<p class="blueText"> Today is a beautiful sunny day!</p>
<button name='bttn-1' type="button">Push</button>

<p class="blueText">Today is also a beautiful hot and sunny day!</p>
<button name='bttn-2' type="button">Push-Toggle</button>
```